# BindingSource.Sort on Structures in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datatable, structure, bindingsource

I have a `Structure` with two `Dates` and, a `Sub New` and also a `Function ToString()`. I also have a `DataGridView`, bound to a `BindingSource` bound to a `DataTable containing objects of my structure`. I am now using `BindingSource.Sort` to order my DataGridView. How does the BindingSource order my Structure objects (looks like by String?) and how can I adjust it? Do I have to adjust the Structure, inherit the BindingSource-Class or how would I get started?

ps. This Structure is just an example. I may have more complex ones in the future.

```
Public Structure dateRange
    Public date1 As Date
    Public date2 As Date
    Sub New(newdt1 As Date, newdt2 As Date)
        date1=newdt1
        date2=newdt2
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return date1.ToString & " - " & date2.ToString
    End Function
End Structure
```

Comment: I clearly misinterpreted the question.  I have deleted my original answer and posted a more relevant one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a type to have a default sort mode then you need to implement the `IComparable` and/or `IComparable(Of T)` interfaces.  It's considered good practice to implement both.  E.g.

```
Public Structure DateRange
    Implements IComparable, IComparable(Of DateRange)

    Public ReadOnly Property StartDate As Date
    Public ReadOnly Property EndDate As Date

    Public Sub New(startDate As Date, endDate As Date)
        Me.StartDate = startDate
        Me.EndDate = endDate
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{StartDate} - {EndDate}"
    End Function

    Public Function CompareTo(obj As Object) As Integer Implements IComparable.CompareTo
        Return CompareTo(DirectCast(obj, DateRange))
    End Function

    Public Function CompareTo(other As DateRange) As Integer Implements IComparable(Of DateRange).CompareTo
        'Sort by start date by default.
        Dim result = StartDate.CompareTo(other.StartDate)

        If result = 0 Then
            'Start dates are the same so sort by end date.
            result = EndDate.CompareTo(other.EndDate)
        End If

        Return result
    End Function

End Structure
```

Notice that this implementation makes use of the implementation provided by the `Date` type to do the heavy lifting.

You can read more about sorting lists [here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/06/sorting-arrays-and-collections-part-1.html).

Comment: On Point! Thank you so much for your effort! How do you actually find that out? I couldn't find that on google nor on SO.

Comment: What you find depends on what you look for and what you look for depends on your understanding of the problem.  Sometimes (often) we look at a problem from the wrong angle to find the correct solution.  I can't recall how I first learned about those interfaces but I'm not sure that I was searching for that specifically at the time. It was quite some time ago now, lost in the mists of time... ;-)